# Ошибка python после компиляции в exe с библиотекой pvporcupine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

После компиляции python файла в exe появляется такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "test1.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pvporcupine\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pvporcupine\_factory.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "pvporcupine\_util.py", line 136, in pv_keyword_paths
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\Users\\egora\\Desktop\\Test1\\dist\\test1\\pvporcupine\\resources/keyword_files\\windows'
```

В скрипте работаю с библиотекой `pvporcupine`